# Дан класс Matrix, нужно сложить две матрицы

Tags: c++, ооп

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix{
private:
    int size = 0;
    int **m = nullptr;
public:
    Matrix() = default;

    Matrix(int n) :size(n){
        m = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            m[i] = new int[size];
        }
    }

    ~Matrix(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            delete[] m[i];
        }
        delete[] m;
    }

    void fill(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                m[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    void show(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
                cout << m[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    Matrix operator+(Matrix& r){
        Matrix temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
                m[i] += r.m[i];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
};

int main(){
    Matrix p(5), r(5), c(5);

    p.fill(); p.show();
    r.fill(); r.show();

    p = p + r;
    p.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так складывайте - в чем проблема?

Comment: не получается, какая-то ошибка. Я не знаю может я не правильно перезагрузил оператор+

Comment: Автор просит сделать за него. Или опишите проблему и что вы пытались сделать для ее решения, или надо закрывать вопрос.

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov _какая-то ошибка_ решается _каким-то образом_. Нужно описание конкретной проблемы.

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov "помощь" - это то, что предоставляют при "просьбе", не так ли?

Comment: Я не прошу сделать всё, я прошу чтоб объяснили мою ошибку. Я вижу Вы не понимаете межу разницей в помощи и в просьбе

Comment: Matrix(const Matrix &g){ m = new int*[size]; for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { m[i] = g.m[size]; } } Я правильно сделал конструктор копирования?

Comment: (1) неправильно, вы должны скопировать и вектора-строки тоже, (2) дополнительные вопросы публикуйте как новый вопрос, а не как ответ

Comment: Matrix(const Matrix &g){
  m = new int*[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
    m[i][j] = g.m[size];
   }
  }
 }
А сейчас? Я добавил ещё один цикл, как я понел

Comment: @VladD можно лишь пожелать вам терпения с этим вопросом...

Comment: Ну я так и понял, что тут только критиковать и банить умею, а как совет так плечами пожимают. Удачи вам!

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov: Всё ещё нет. Вы по сути должны сделать всё, что вы делаете в конструкторе `Matrix(int n)` (возможно, стоит вынести этот код в отдельную процедуру), плюс перенести данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, что вы делаете.

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix& r){
    Matrix temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            m[i] += r.m[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Вы заводите переменную для суммы (`temp`), затем почему-то изменяете левое слагаемое (`m[i] += ...`), переменную для суммы не меняете, и возвращаете нетронутую пустую матрицу.

Кроме того, у вас нет оператора присваивания и копирующего конструктора, хотя вы ими пользуетесь. Да-да, пользуетесь, вы ведь возвращаете матрицу по значению и копируете сумму в одну из матриц.

Вы должны:

- проверить совпадение размеров левой и правой части (и подумать о реакции на ошибку)
- выделить матрицу для суммы нужного размера
- складывать поэлементные суммы в неё
- правильно определить конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания
- (опционально) можно подумать о конструкторе перемещения, когда освоите C++14

Кстати, конструктор без параметров для матрицы не нужен и даже вреден, уберите его!

Comment: В моём случае все матрицы 5 на 5

Comment: То, что ошибка не случается в вашем примере, не говорит, что код правильный. Оператор сложения обязан быть готов к тому, что на вход придут матрицы разных размеров.